# How to set the bits/pixels to a WriteableBitmap (with BlackWhite format (1bpp))

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a binary image in C#/WPF using the WriteableBitmap class, with the BlackWhite Format which is 1 bit per pixel.

However, it seems the my image is very distorted when finished. Using different formats (such as brg32) works just fine. The pixel data is stored in a BitArray. The images vary from 1000x1000 to 3000x3000 pixels.

Here is the code I am current using:

```
unsafe
            {
                int colorOffset = 0;
                int pixelOffset = 0;
                byte color = 0;
                int pBackBuffer = (int)_image.BackBuffer;

                for (int y = 0; y < mapData.Height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < mapData.Width; x++)
                    {

                        if (mapData.Data[y * mapData.Height + x])
                        {
                            //Set the pixel to white
                            color += 1;
                        }

                        //Shift the pixel position by 1
                        color = (byte)(color << 1);

                        //If 8 pixels have been written, write it to the backbuffer
                        if (++colorOffset == 8)
                        {
                            pixelOffset = ((y * mapData.Height) + x) / 8;
                            *(byte*)(pBackBuffer + pixelOffset) = color;
                            color = 0;
                            colorOffset = 0;
                        }

                    }
                }
                //Update the image
                _image.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, mapData.Width, mapData.Height));
            }
```

As you can see, I am writing 8 pixels / bits , and then copying it to the back buffer. Perhaps someone who has a bit more knowledge in this topic could help. I've also tried directly copying the BitArray to a byte array, then copy the byte array to the backbuffer (and using the WritePixels function as well), both of which have not helped.

Regards,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are not using `BackBufferStride` property to compute address of the next line of pixels. Also note that you are missing some pixels if map width is not a multiple of 8. I didn't test the code, but i would have written it like this:

```
unsafe
{
    int colorOffset = 0;
    int pixelOffset = 0;
    byte color = 0;
    byte* pBackBuffer = (byte*)_image.BackBuffer;
    for(int y = 0; y < mapData.Height; y++)
    {
        // get a pointer to first pixel in a line y
        byte* pixLine = pBackBuffer;
        for(int x = 0; x < mapData.Width; x++)
        {

            // fix #1: offset = y * width + x, not y * height + x
            var mapOffset = y * mapData.Width + x;

            if (mapData.Data[mapOffset])
            {
                //Set the pixel to white
                color += 1;
            }

            //Shift the pixel position by 1
            color = (byte)(color << 1);

            //If 8 pixels have been written, write it to the backbuffer
            if(++colorOffset == 8)
            {
                *pixLine++ = color;
                color = 0;
                colorOffset = 0;
            }

        }
        // fix #2: copy any pixels left
        if(colorOffset != 0)
        {
            *pixLine++ = color;
            colorOffset = 0;
            color = 0;
        }

        // fix #3: next line offset = previous line + stride, they are aligned
        pBackBuffer += _image.BackBufferStride;
    }
    //Update the image
    _image.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, mapData.Width, mapData.Height));
}
```